# Powerapps UpdateContext after Patch

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

I have a 'Sign Up' button in my app that adds the logged in user into a sharepoint list. The code (which works perfectly) is currently -

```
Patch(
    EVENTPARTICIPANTS;
    Defaults(EVENTPARTICIPANTS);
{
   EVENTID: Gallery3.Selected.EVENTID;
  NAME:{
            '@odata.type': "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser";
            Department: "";
            Claims: "i:0#.f|membership|" & User().Email;
            DisplayName: User().FullName;
            Email: User().Email;
            JobTitle: "";
            Picture: User().Image
        }
 }
 )
```

I'm trying to figure out how to add an updateContext after it, so my confirmation popup box will be visible, but I can't get the syntax right.

Can someone please tell me why this doesn't work? Thanks!

```
Patch(
    EVENTPARTICIPANTS;
    Defaults(EVENTPARTICIPANTS);
{
   EVENTID: Gallery3.Selected.EVENTID;
  NAME:{
            '@odata.type': "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser";
            Department: "";
            Claims: "i:0#.f|membership|" & User().Email;
            DisplayName: User().FullName;
            Email: User().Email;
            JobTitle: "";
            Picture: User().Image
        }
 }
 )
;
 UpdateContext({varShowPopup:true})
```

Comment: From a first glance the syntax looks fine. What error do you get?

Comment: Weirdly enough.. I had to add two semicolons before the updateContext.. It didn't like just one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
Patch(
    EVENTPARTICIPANTS;
    Defaults(EVENTPARTICIPANTS);
    {
        EVENTID: Gallery3.Selected.EVENTID;
        NAME:{
            '@odata.type': "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedUser";
            Department: "";
            Claims: "i:0#.f|membership|" & User().Email;
            DisplayName: User().FullName;
            Email: User().Email;
            JobTitle: "";
            Picture: User().Image
        }
    }
);;
UpdateContext({varShowPopup:true})
```

It should work for you!

Answer (score 2):

In the locale that you are editing your app, the list separator is `;` - which probably indicates that you are in a place that uses `,` as the decimal separator (instead of `.`). That changes the chaining operator from `;` to `;;`, which is what you found out you need to use to make your scenario work. You can find more details at https://learn.microsoft.com/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/global-apps#formula-separators-and-chaining-operator